# Data Form Webpart Customising display

Tags: data-form-web-part

I've added a dataformweboart that pulls data from the user profile web service.

Upon display I can see the Manager field but the output is in the form of domain\jonesp I want to see Peter Jones or at least Jones, Peter.

In Profile Services it shows the resolved Jones, Peter which is where the DataForm Webpart is getting its info from.

So problem is most likely the DataForm Webpart

Is this possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The user profile service returns the manager as a string in the domain\username format. You could use that to make another call and pull in the value via joined subview possibly. If the field were returned as a user field like a normal person/group field in a list you could use the person.title field. This is not the case however and we just get a domain\user string back from the SOAP web service.